# View pager 2: Depth Page Transformation make fragment click events disable on pager swipe up

Tags: android, android-pagetransformer, android-viewpager2

I am using viewpager2 with fragmentStateAdapter.
Also, setting page transformer as DepthPageTransformation(transition is working correctly the way I want)

But when I swipe up the pages, the on click events on that fragment works on double click(event works after clicking twice on it)

If I remove pageTransformation from the viewPager, then it works fine.
So, not able to understand that why is transformation causing click event problem.

```
    private static final float MIN_SCALE = 0.75f;
    public void transformPage(@NonNull View view, float position) {
        int pageHeight = view.getHeight();
        if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
            // This page is way off-screen to the left.
            view.setAlpha(0f);
            Log.d("batman",position+" <-1");
        } else if (position <= 0) { // [-1,0]
            // Use the default slide transition when moving to the left page
            view.setAlpha(1f);
            view.setTranslationY(0f);
            view.setScaleX(1f);
            view.setScaleY(1f);
            Log.d("batman",position+" <=0");
        } else if (position <= 1) { // (0,1]
            // Fade the page out.
            view.setAlpha(1 - position);
            // Counteract the default slide transition
            view.setTranslationY(pageHeight * -position);
            // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
            float scaleFactor = MIN_SCALE
                    + (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - Math.abs(position));
            view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
            view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);
            Log.d("batman",position+" <=1");
        } else { // (1,+Infinity]
            // This page is way off-screen to the right.
            view.setAlpha(0f);
            Log.d("batman",position+" else");
        }
    }
}
```

```
HomeFragment(adapter setting):

mAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this);
        setPageChangeListener();
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
      //  mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        mViewPager.setPageTransformer( new DepthPageTransformer());
```

I want that button click event should work at one click when the page is swiped up.

Comment: Try to change  `mViewPager.setPageTransformer( new DepthPageTransformer());` to  `mViewPager.setPageTransformer(true,new DepthPageTransformer());` and add     `view.bringToFront();` for `(position <= 0)` after  `view.setScaleY(1f);`

Comment: @Piyush ViewPager2 only allows transformation object in setPageTransformer(), does not supports boolean value in it. Also, view.bringToFront() throws this exception (java.lang.IllegalStateException: Page can only be offset by a positive amount, not by -1138)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clicks of the previous fragment were getting disabled on swipe up because I was updating my fragment which is added in view pager from onPageSelected() listener, so that was making the button work on double click.

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    homePresenter.onPageSelected();
    currentPg = position;
}
```

Maybe we cannot update our fragment from this listener.